# Google Apps Transition - Free/Busy with Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, g-suite, calendar, exchange-migration

Over the past few weeks I've been working to create a flawless Google Apps test pilot for our users despite Google's lack of official support for Exchange 2010 in all migration utilities. So far, I've been able to work out all kinks except one.

The last hurdle is the synchronizing of users' free/busy data between Exchange and Google Apps. Google provides the [calendar connector kit](http://code.google.com/p/google-calendar-connectors/wiki/Overview) with official support for Exchange 2003 and 2007, but I'm seeing WebDAV-related error messages in the logs and that's one of the big things removed between 2007 and 2010.

I don't mind diving back into troubleshooting, but since it's not officially supported, I thought I'd check here first to see if what I'm trying to do is at least possible. Has anyone else found a working solution for the synchronization of free/busy data between Exchange 2010 and Google Apps?

Comment: +1 awesome username :D (and very interesting question...)

Answer (score 2):

a not-so-well known feature of Exchange 2010 is Internet Calendar Publishing.
If you set that up, you'll be able to check those calendar's appointments and import them into Google's users mailboxes I guess?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607475.aspx

Hope it helps...